# program received signal sigterm

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

In my app there is an image view where I am performing two operations:
1. Reflect Image :

-(void)reflectImage{

```
UIImage *alterImage=[[UIImage alloc]init];
alterImage=photoView.image;
UIImageOrientation flippedOrientation = alterImage.imageOrientation;
if (flippedOrientation==UIImageOrientationUp) {
    flippedOrientation = UIImageOrientationDownMirrored;

}
else if (flippedOrientation==UIImageOrientationDown) {
    flippedOrientation = UIImageOrientationUpMirrored;

}
else if (flippedOrientation==UIImageOrientationDownMirrored) {
    flippedOrientation = UIImageOrientationUp;

}
else if (flippedOrientation==UIImageOrientationUpMirrored) {
    flippedOrientation = UIImageOrientationDown;

}
UIImage * flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:alterImage.CGImage scale:alterImage.scale orientation:flippedOrientation];
photoView.image=flippedImage;
```

}

And 2. SimpleImage:

```
-(IBAction)getSimpleImage:(id)sender{


    [photoView setImage:simpleImage];


}
```

simpleImage is the orignal image.
App is crashing when I reflect the image and get back the orignal image.
It is showing error as "program received signal sigterm".

Comment: how do you initialize you original image? i think that you original image is released. (PS. your first line is leaking memory! just delete it

Comment: I have used uiimagepickercontroller to assign image to imageview and also assigned it to simlpeImage. And as you told i deleted the first line but still its crashing.

Comment: try [simlpeImage retain]; after assigning